# missing view controller in navigation stack when presenting a MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, messageui

I have a navigation stack consisted of view controllers A, B, C.

In view controller C, I present an `MFMailComposeViewController` like so:

```
let mailComposeViewController = MFMailComposeViewController()
mailComposeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self
self.present(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In my dismissal delegate

```
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
  controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I expected the app to pop back to controller C when the mail compose VC is dismissed, but then the app always pop back to B. I put a print statement in the dismiss delegate and saw that C is no longer in my navigation stack...

What's going on? How can I make the mail compose vc pop back to C?